# c++ quiz project not working because of some header files

Tags: c++

how can i add turbo c++ header files to dev c++ manually i know some of them are already included but like process.h and windows.h header file are not included can somebody plsss help soon

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

and i've seen a gotoxy function in many projects but can't find its definition why? and when it's used in dev c++ it always gives an error

[Error] 'gotoxy' was not declared in this scope

can somebody help on it?

Comment: The relationship between your subject line and the rest of your post is obscure, to put it mildly.

Comment: It's more about finding the right headers for the functions you're importing, not necessarily including the same exact set. What functions / declarations / definitions are you missing besides gotoxy? That's from conio.h and depending where you're trying to run the code you're compiling you may have to switch conio out for a different library, e.g. ncurses.

Comment: gotoxy ? maybe it's a user defined function.

Answer (score 4):

The `gotoxy()` function and the `conio.h` are not standard functions/headers and are deprecated. In Windows, you can replace/reimplement `gotoxy` in terms of the [SetConsoleCursorPosition()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx) function (on Linux, you should use the ncurses library, instead, for this sort of console I/O).

An example of how to do this is outlined in [this forum on cprogramming.com](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044844545&id=1043284392):

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
   COORD coord;
   coord.X = x;
   coord.Y = y;
   SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

(Perhaps you should notify your instructor so that they stop giving out assignments/examples that assume certain headers/functions that are no longer available on any modern installation).